# Script only processes 1st Line of input file

Tags: linux, bash

bash script to read a file and process commands remotely.
It currently only processes the first line (server1)

Need to remotely process 3 commands on server1 , then server2 ......

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    sshpass -f password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$line zgrep "^A30=" /var/tmp/logs1/messages.* |  >> Output.txt
    sshpass -f password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$line zgrep "^A30=" /var/tmp/logs2/messages.* |  >> Output.txt
    sshpass -f password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$line zgrep "^A30=" /var/tmp/logs3/messages.* |  >> Output.txt
done < file1
```

file1:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

Comment: What is ` |  >> Output.txt` supposed to do?

Comment: That construction may work in some shells, but you probably just want to do `done < file 1 >> Output.txt`

Answer (score 4):

`sshpass` is reading from the same file descriptor as the while loop, and exhausting that input before `read` is able to read it.  Best thing is to close its stdin explicitly `sshpass <&- ...` or redirect from /dev/null `sshpass < /dev/null`.

Another option is to let `sshpass` inherit stdin from the script and read from a different file descriptor:

```
while read line <&3; do 
   ...
done 3< file1
```

Comment: Thxs your suggestions worked.